# How to restart a for loop iteration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to force a for loop to restart if a condition is not stratified. I can do it with while since I want the loop to run for a certain number of iterations. I tried to set `iter=iter-1` inside the `if` statement but it did not work. Any suggestions?

```
R=2*10^3;
lamda= 0.00001;
h=100;
a = 9.6117;
b = 0.1581;


for iter=1:10

     M=poissrnd(lamda*R^2);

     xx=R*rand(1,M); 
     yy=R*rand(1,M); 
     zz=ones(1,M)*h;

     BS=[xx' yy' zz'];
     user=[0,0, 0];

     s=pdist2(BS(:,1:2),user(1,1:2));    
     anga=atand(h./s);
     PL=1./(1+(a*exp(b*(a-anga))));
     berRV=binornd(1,PL);

     if berRV(1)==1       
         % do something    
     else
         % repeat
     end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work"? What was the error message?

Comment: @Bebs No error message. I mean it did not restart the current iteration.

Comment: Do you mean `iter = 1 ?`

Comment: @Bebs No. I mean if we are at `iter 9` and `berRV(1)==1` is not satisfied, then I want the loop to do `iter 9` again. I want the code to run until `berRV(1)==1` is satisfied `n` times.

Comment: you cannot change a `for` loop iterator within a loop in Matlab. Once you defined `iter` at the top of the `for` loop, Matlab will increment/decrement it as specified in the loop definition regardless of what modification you try to do within the loop. You have to use another variable if you want to be able to act on it within the loops.

Comment: @Hoki what do you mean by using another variable?

Comment: I mean you cannot do anything to `iter` once the loop is started, so if you want to count something on the side you have to use a different variable. Trying to understand your problem statement: do you mean you want to "run the loop _at least_ 9 times (even if `berRV(1)==1` before that), but if necessary continue to run the loop `n` more times until `berRV(1)==1`" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a while loop, with a comparison to whether the number of needed results have been identified. See the comment about saving your found values, as you hadn't specified what needs to be done when the condition you're searching for is satisfied.

```
R=2*10^3;
lamda= 0.00001;
h=100;
a = 9.6117;
b = 0.1581;

total_results_found = 0;
needed_results_found = 10;

while total_results_found < needed_results_found

    M=poissrnd(lamda*R^2);

    xx=R*rand(1,M);
    yy=R*rand(1,M);
    zz=ones(1,M)*h;

    BS=[xx' yy' zz'];
    user=[0,0, 0];

    s=pdist2(BS(:,1:2),user(1,1:2));
    anga=atand(h./s);
    PL=1./(1+(a*exp(b*(a-anga))));
    berRV=binornd(1,PL);

    if berRV(1)==1
        % save the result here

        % iterate the counter
        total_results_found = total_results_found + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Will this continue until 10 iterations in which `berRV(1)==1` are done? I tried using a counter inside the second `if` statement and I got only `1`. I am not sure if this is doing what I want. I would like to execute a certain code 10 times for example with the condition `berRV(1)==1`. I mean I do not want to execute the code until the condition is met once and then stop.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect what I believe you're looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach here would be with a `while` loop inside the `for` loop:

```
for iter=1:10
    berRV(1) = 0
    while berRV(1)~=1       
        % original loop code here
    end
    % do something
end
```

[Sadly, MATLAB does not have a `do...while` loop, it would make the above a little cleaner.]

Answer (score 1):

While the other two solutions are perfectly valid, I wanted to give you another solution, which I think is the closest to the logic you provided in the question.

```
for iter=1:10
    while 1
        % loop code here
        if berRV(1) == 1
            break
        end
    end
end
```

The idea is similar to the one Cris presents, namely that you repeat the body of the for-loop until some condition is met. The difference lies solely in how you terminate the while loop,

Comment: Yeah, they're both ways of simulating the `do...until` loop that MATLAB doesn't have.